# Creating word histograms from lists of strings

Tags: string-manipulation, probability-or-statistics

Consider the following:

```
StringData1={"Dog","Dog","Dog","Dog","Duck","Duck","Duck","Rabbit","House"};
StringData2={"A dog is in the house.","A dog is outside.",
    "Why is everybody talking about a dog?", "Dog", "The duck died in the house.", 
    "The duck is actually a rabbit.", "Duck", "And the rabbit in fact is a dog", 
    "I have a dog in my house."};
```

Using the following function, it is quite easy to plot a histogram for `StringData1`. However the options remain fixed.

```
StringHistogram[list_] :=
 Module[{counter, strings, numbers},
  counter = {First@#, Length@#} & /@ (GatherBy@list);
  strings = First /@ counter;
  numbers = Last /@ counter;

  BarChart[numbers, ChartLabels -> strings]
  ]
```

In case of `StringData2` I was wondering whether it would be possible to chop up each sentence into single words (e.g.`{Sentence1,...} -> {{Word1, Word2,...},...}`) and then to run `StringHistogram` on `Flatten@StringData2New`, whereas `StringData2New` is of the form `{{Word1, Word2,...},...}`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have a slightly different strategy for splittling the string than [rcollyer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4834/531), because you can stick the pattern into `StringSplit` directly instead of needing to do a `StringReplace` first to prepare the string for splitting. For instance:

```
In[141]:= StringSplit["A dog is in the house.", Except[WordCharacter]]
Out[141]= {"A", "dog", "is", "in", "the", "house"}
```

Also, you can make `StringHistogram` simpler by using the built-in [`Tally`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Tally.html) function, which you've reimplemented (pretty darn well, I must say):

```
StringHistogram[list_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
 With[{tally = Tally@list},
  BarChart[tally[[All, 2]],
   BarOrigin -> Left,
   ChartLabels -> tally[[All, 1]],
   FilterRules[{opts}, Options[BarChart]]
   ]]
```

I use the [`BarOrigin` option](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BarOrigin.html) to make the bars come from the side, which makes everything much easier to read when you have many strings, and I pass options to `BarChart` in order to make tweaking things easier:

```
StringHistogram[
 StringSplit[StringData2, Except[WordCharacter]] // Flatten, 
 ImageSize -> 500, BaseStyle -> "Label"]
```

[image: big histogram]

Comment: `Except[WordCharacter]` is a very good alternative, and I'm ashamed to admit I never think of `Except`, +1.

Answer (score 9):

You're looking for [`StringSplit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/StringSplit.html). In your case, I would do this

```
StringSplit[{"A dog is in the house.","A dog is outside."}]
```

which returns

```
(* {{"A", "dog", "is", "in", "the", "house."}, 
    {"A", "dog", "is", "outside."}} *)
```

Unfortunately, that leaves in the punctuation. To rid yourself of the punctuation, I would use [`StringReplace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/StringReplace.html) first, as follows

```
StringSplit @ StringReplace[{"A dog is in the house.", "A dog is outside."},
  RegularExpression["[[:punct:]]"]
```

which gives

```
(* {{"A", "dog", "is", "in", "the", "house"}, 
    {"A", "dog", "is", "outside"}} *)
```

Note the use of the character class in the [`RegularExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RegularExpression.html); it makes specifying all punctuation easier.

Answer (score 6):

Regarding the first part of your question, I would rewrite `StringHistogram` like this:

```
StringHistogram[list_] := BarChart[#2, ChartLabels -> #1] & @@ Transpose[Tally@list]
```

If you want to supply additional options, you can extend this as:

```
StringHistogram[list_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
    BarChart[#2, ChartLabels -> #1, opts] & @@ Transpose[Tally@list]
```

---

I think Pillsy's suggestion to split the strings is very clean. Here's another equally clean approach using `StringCases`:

```
StringCases[StringData2, x : WordCharacter .. :> x]
```

Answer (score 2):

The `TextWords` feature was introduced in 2015.  `TextWords` connects to the internet so that is a possible limitation.

[image]

---

```
Clear["Global`*"];
StringData1 = {"Dog", "Dog", "Dog", "Dog", "Duck", "Duck", "Duck", 
   "Rabbit", "House"};
StringData2 = {"A dog is in the house.", "A dog is outside.", 
   "Why is everybody talking about a dog?", "Dog", 
   "The duck died in the house.", "The duck is actually a rabbit.", 
   "Duck", "And the rabbit in fact is a dog", 
   "I have a dog in my house."};
tc1 = TextWords[StringData2] // Flatten // DeleteStopwords // 
    ToLowerCase // Tally // ReverseSortBy[Last][#] &
BarChart[tc1[[All, 2]], BarOrigin -> Left, 
 ChartLabels -> tc1[[All, 1]]]
```

Users can compare results by excluding `DeleteStopWords` from the above.

[image]

---

`StringSplit` was updated in 2020. Can't say exactly what was updated but another syntax can be used for such cases that was most likely not present in 2012.

```
Flatten@StringSplit[
  StringData2, {PunctuationCharacter, WhitespaceCharacter}]
```

> {"A", "dog", "is", "in", "the", "house", "A", "dog", "is", "outside",
> \ "Why", "is", "everybody", "talking", "about", "a", "dog", "Dog", 
> "The", "duck", "died", "in", "the", "house", "The", "duck", "is", 
> "actually", "a", "rabbit", "Duck", "And", "the", "rabbit", "in", 
> "fact", "is", "a", "dog", "I", "have", "a", "dog", "in", "my", 
> "house"}

and

```
Flatten@TextWords[StringData2] == 
 Flatten@StringSplit[
   StringData2, {PunctuationCharacter, WhitespaceCharacter}]
```

> True